# Qt Creator: Highlight lines changed after the last commit

Tags: version-control, qt-creator

As a code quality checker, That would be nice if I can see modified lines since the last commit highlighted. There is an option in **Tools** menu that you can `diff` your current working directory with the last cloned code, but the result is all of the differences. I need an option that when I change a newly cloned code or apply a patch to it, I can see modified lines highlighted just inside the source code editor.

Comment: So just to be clear, you are expecting either answer "QtC has no such feature" or answer "Yes, enable it like this..."?

Comment: @hyde or maybe you can use this plugin...